# Have a parameter applied to service for Upstart

Tags: scripts, services, upstart

I want to run my `webcit` service with the `-f` option, how do I put that in the service script (/etc/init.d/webcit)?

The lines that look relevant are:

```
RUNDIR=/var/run/webcit
PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
DESC="Citadel Groupware Webserver "
NAME=webcit
DAEMON=/usr/sbin/$NAME
DAEMON_ARGS=""
PIDFILE=$RUNDIR/$NAME.pid
SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/webcit
SENDCOMMAND=/usr/sbin/sendcommand
DEFAULT=/etc/default/webcit
LOGDIR=/var/log/webcit/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the file `/etc/default/webcit` and change the first line to

```
export WEBCIT_APACHEFLAG='-f'
```

then restart the service

```
sudo service webcit restart
```